# How to read online text file in pandas?

Tags: nlp

I am doing a Machine Translation, I don't want to download data, instead of I need to use pandas to read the file online, But I won't. Please help meeeeee

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.statmt.org/europarl/v7/fr-en.tgz')
```

I am getting many error, please help me with this. ...

Answer (score 0):

Found some answers,

```
# !wget https://www.statmt.org/europarl/v7/fr-en.tgz  # download the tgz file 
# !tar -xvf /content/fr-en.tgz  # extract the tgz file
```

If you know anything, please share!